# Confusion regarding a program on structures

Tags: c, struct, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(void)
{
    struct computer
    {
        float cost;
        int year;
        int cpu_speed;
        char cpu_type[16];
    } model;

    printf(“The type of the CPU inside your computer?\n”);
    gets(model.cpu_type);
    printf(“The speed(MHz) of the CPU?\n”);
    scanf(“%d”, &model.cpu_speed);
    printf(“The year your computer was made?\n”);
    scanf(“%d”, &model.year);
    printf(“How much you paid for the computer?\n”);
    scanf(“%f”, &model.cost);

    printf(“Here are what you entered:\n”);
    printf(“Year: %d\n”, model.year);
    printf(“Cost: $%6.2f\n”, model.cost);
    printf(“CPU type: %s\n”, model.cpu_type);
    printf(“CPU speed: %d MHz\n”, model.cpu_speed);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code is from Teach Yourself C in 24 hours,but it shows stray errors while being run.

In the book,an output has also been displayed.

In the output,the cost of the model is `$1234.56`. How can `1234.56` fit into `%6.2f`... I mean for `%6.2f` we'll get only `234.56`,right?

Comment: *"it shows stray errors"*  What errors? [edit] and add *complete* error messages. Also, see [mcve].

Comment: You don't really have smart quotes in your source, do you?

Comment: Get a better textbook. Nobody should ever use `gets()`. Also, `main(void)` should be `int main(void)`

Comment: /temp/file.cpp:12:2: error: stray ‘\342’ in program...and many more.

Comment: [why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: what about the second part regarding %6.2f???

Comment: %6.2f means it'll have at least 6 digits and at most 2 decimal places - if the number is larger it'll take up more space.

Comment: @ChrisTurner: Not 6 *digits* (at least not with `%f`),

Comment: `main(void)` should be `int main(void)`...

Comment: so 1234.56 will become 234.56,right??

Comment: @ScottHunter OK - digits and a decimal point.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage The program still displays errors,saying that 'The' has not been declared,in the first printf statement

Comment: @Susan: No, not right.  It will still be 1234.56 (see answer below, and Chris Turner's comment).

Comment: @Susan no. See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/hQsirC)

Comment: @Susan That's because you're using printer's quotation marks, as others have already pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

You have invalid character for double quote `“` and `”` which are causing the stray error. You probably have them copied them from some other site or pdf. Otherwise you need to check your keyboard setting.

The correct double quote is `"`.

Comment: @ScottHunter The actual error is [this](http://ideone.com/yzBUrt) as commented by OP

Comment: @ScottHunter I have actually copied the source and compiled to see the  error and fix.

Answer (score 1):

The 6 in `%6.2f` is the *minimum* field width.

Comment: Isn't it like this-we count 6 places and then 2 backwards(for 2 in 6.2) and then a place backward again for the decimal point?  _ _ _ _. _ _   So there'll be 3 places before the decimal and 2 after it???If not,how actually do we count the places??

Comment: `printf` never truncates the whole part of a floating point number. @Susan, please ask this as a separate question and you'll get more a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You used strange chars for strings: you used `“` but you must use `"`